# Storing symfony session data in two different session storage

Tags: php, session, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4 (lts) and i need to store user session data in two different storage systems.
When the user is connected to the back office, I will keep the default storage.
When my user is connected to the front office, I need to store data in database.

I think that i need to declare two-session handlers in the framework.yaml but I'm not sure about that.
Maybe, i need to create a custom SessionHandler to detect the route and firewall matched by the request to dispatch the session managment in the good session system ?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

1. Implement / configure a session handler for [loading / saving the sessions in the database](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/session/database.html)
2. Implement a custom session handler that implements `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\AbstractSessionHandler`.
3. Inject your two session handlers (front-office / back-office) [using DI](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type) into this service.
4. Implement the required functions and your custom logic which session handler should be used.
5. Set [`framework.session.handler_id`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#config-framework-session-handler-id) to your new service.